# Getting Product name and code to Contact form

Tags: php, opencart

I have added two fields in the contact form.

```
Product Name:
Product Code:
```

I have a pre-order button on the product page so all products that is 0 quantity will have this button enabled. When the user click this button they will be redirected to the contact form.

```
<a href="http://localhost/store/index.php?route=information/contact"><button>Pre-Order</button></a>
```

Now How do i Autofill the Product Name and Product Code input in the Contact form when the user click on the Pre-Order button on the product page?

**Sample Scenario:**

Customer is browsing on the product Lenovo Motherboard with Product code: LV032, But he finds out that this product is out of stock and Pre-Order is only the available option. So he clicks on the Pre-Order button then customer is redirected to the contact form with the product name and product code fields already filled with the Name and Code of the Product that the customer want's to pre-order.

**EDIT:**

I got a working solution using sessions on the product page then using the session on the contact form. Please advise if I'm doing a right thing.

Answer (score 3):

i don't exactly buy what you are trying to do, here is what i think you want to do

```
<a href="localhost/application/perorder.php?id=123&name=thinkpad">Pre Order</a>
```

now perorder.php should look like this

```
$id = $_GET['id']; $name = $_GET['name'];
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name;?>" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However I got it working by using sessions. I'll write it as an answer so you can see.

Comment: yeah session are only used for this kind of purchasing jobs, actually the problem was that you were using a link, and i don't exactly know how to do with that, so i used GET for it :)

Comment: Yeah sorry about the link. Anyway I posted my working solution. I don't know if it's right way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing this.

I added this two lines in the product.php located in `controller/product/product.php`

```
$_SESSION['prodname'] = $product_info['name'];
$_SESSION['prodcode'] = $product_info['model'];
```

Now in the contact form controller contact.php located in `controller/information/contact.php`
I added this code.

```
if (isset($this->request->post['prodname'])) {
            $this->data['prodname'] = $this->request->post['prodname'];
        } else {
            if(isset($_SESSION['prodname'])) {
            $this->data['prodname'] = $_SESSION['prodname'];
            } else {
            $this->data['prodname'] = '';
            }
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['prodcode'])) {
            $this->data['prodcode'] = $this->request->post['prodcode'];
        } else {
            if(isset($_SESSION['prodcode'])){
            $this->data['prodcode'] = $_SESSION['prodcode'];
            } else {
            $this->data['prodcode'] = '';
            }
        }
```

Then on the success function inside controller contact.php I added this line before `$this->response->setOutput($this->render());`

```
unset($_SESSION['prodname']);
unset($_SESSION['prodcode']);       
$this->response->setOutput($this->render());
```

Now It's working. I don't know if this is the right way to do it. If anyone has better answer please shed me some light. THanks.

Comment: This is not very happy solution. Just because when You set those data to the session then anytime I just would open normal contact form after I have visited some product I would have the product ID and product name filled in even if I do not want to do a preorder... Using the product ID and product name in the link's GET part as answer from **@avinashizhere** suggested is much more better and convenient way of solving Your problem.